# How were C's different signatures for main supported before _Generic?

Tags: c, generics, program-entry-point, signature

`_Generic` became available with C11, and before that in C99, `tgmath.h` included similar functionality using compiler specific hacks.

but how did main have multiple signatures back in K&R C, or C89/C90?

there's at least 2 function signatures for main() that I'm aware of:

1: `int main(int argc, const char *argv[]);`

2: `int main(void);`

Comment: What answer other than *"compiler specific hacks"* are you looking for?

Comment: Multiple signatures for `main()` have nothing whatever to do with `_Generic`, then or now.

Comment: I was under the impression `_start` would have to support multiple declarations, and not the compiler?

in general, I'm just looking for details on how the system worked in the first place.

Comment: The code that invokes `main` is compiler-specific, so can contain any number of necessary hacks. Moreover, the declaration is just that: a declaration. The actual definition doesn't have to agree with the declaration as long as it more-or-less matches the calling convention. Specifically: the caller can provide argc and argv, and the callee can simply ignore them, because the C calling convention allows this.

Comment: `main()` can have one of several different signatures, but it cannot have *multiple* signatures. Only one is permitted.

Comment: `_start` (defined in `crt0.o`) calls `__libc_start_main`, which eventually always calls `int main(int argc, const char *argv[], const char *envp);`. For different architectures, C will handle `int main(void);` in different ways, but on x86, and most other architectures, it is valid to just ignore trailing arguments, since cleanup happens automatically with architectures supporting stackframes.

Comment: [Additional reading material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: "I was under the impression _start would have to support multiple declarations, and not the compiler?" -- Why? The compiler is what sees the `main` signature, so if the different signatures have to be handled differently (in most implementations they don't), the compiler would have to do so. "how the system worked in the first place" -- the same way as now, since _Generic and tgmath had no effect on this. If you want to know how it's done in a specific implementation, look at the generated code.

Comment: I've edited the title -- the question isn't about multiple entry points, which is a quite different topic.

Answer (score 4):

> but how did main have multiple signatures back in K&R C, or C89/C90?

`main` *did not* have multiple signatures *per se* in K&R C.  That version had no sense of "signature" as you mean it.  Although functions did have expectations about the number and types of their arguments, and their behavior was defined only if those expectations were satisfied, function arguments did not constitute a part of function declarations.

The following quotation from section 5.11 of the first edition of *The C Programming Language* (Kernighan & Ritchie, 1978) may be illuminating:

> When `main` is called to begin execution, it is called with two arguments.

The statement is unconditional: `main` is (always) called with two arguments in C as described by K&R.  Compilers could do whatever they wanted or needed to deal with cases where those parameters were not declared.

The case is not really different in C90 or any later version of C (all of which still support K&R-style functions definitions).  Even when `main` is declared with a prototype, implementations do whatever they want or need to do.  For example, maybe they generate code for a standard signature, and perform any necessary patch-up of recursive calls to `main()` during linking.  Or maybe they generate code for whatever (supported) declaration of `main()` is provided, and deal with it in some kind of OS-specific wrapper.  Maybe nothing special is even needed in some implementations.

Answer (score 3):

The C Standard only requires the implementation to support the two signatures given in the question,

```
1: int main(int argc, const char *argv[]);

2: int main(void);
```

For calling conventions where the caller pops the arguments off the calling stack, the calling sequence for (1) works fine for (2) -- the caller pushes the arguments onto the stack, the callee (`main`) never uses them, and the caller removes them from the stack.

For calling conventions where the callee pops the arguments off the calling stack, `main` would have to be compiled differently depending on which signature is used. This would be a problem in implementations with a fixed piece of startup code in the C runtime, since it doesn't know how `main` was declared. The easiest way to deal with that is to always use a "caller pops" calling convention for `main`, and this is in fact how Microsoft's C compiler works -- see, e.g., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gd-gr-gv-gz-calling-convention, which states that other calling conventions are ignored when applied to `main`.

P.S.

- _Generic and tgmath.h had no effect on any of this.
- There were no signatures in K&R C, only the names of the arguments and optional type declarations for them, so there was only one possible calling convention for `main`.

So, none of these language changes over the decades has had any effect on how `main` is called.

Comment: Small clarification necessary: *"Only the two signatures given in the question, are allowed by the **C89/C90** Standard."* C99 added implementation defined ones.

Comment: @user694733 Thanks, adjusted the wording.

Answer (score 1):

`C` had and has no munged function signatures.  Certainly nothing parameter-specific.  Most compilers prepended (and some appended) an underscore ("_") to create a poor-man's linker namespace which made it easy to prevent symbol name collisions.

So the C runtime startup would always have one unambiguous symbol to startup.  Most often `_main`.

```
start:
 ;#  set up registers
 ;#  set up runtime environment:
 ;#  set up stack, initialize heap, connect stdin, stdout, stderr, etc.
 ;#  obtain environment and format for use with "envp"
 ;#  obtain command line arguments and set up for access with "argv"
 push  envp
 push  argv
 push  argc    ; number of arguments in argv
 call  _main

 push  r0
 call  exit

.end  start
```